# is there any chance to host firebase app without their hosting

Tags: firebase, project, backendless

I have a question, so im currently building back-end less app with firebase( auth and database).
So, my question is how will work if my hosting is different(for example: superhosting.bg).If upload my app there,what should i need to run properly my app ?Can you explain me a little bit?

Comment: The question is unclear. Are you asking if you can put Firebase *database* on another host or are you asking if you can put your website/UI on another host? Or both? Or... something else? Also, how does backendless fit into the picture? Backendless has it's own database, structure etc and is not related to Firebase. Can you clarify so we can provide accurate answers?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Authentication and Realtime Database can be used from any hosting provider. There is no need to host your web site on Firebase Hosting. Just follow the [setup instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) (ignoring the ones for Firebase Hosting), and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase requires you to use Google servers. You cannot run firebase outside of Google's server-side environment. However, since you mentioned [backendless](https://backendless.com) (full disclosure - I am the founder), if you were to build your app with it, you can run it anywhere where Docker/Kubernetes runs.

Comment: You want to tell me , if i upload my project to some different host(not firebase) my app would not work ?

Comment: I think OP is asking about using Firebase Auth and Database from a different hosting provider.

Comment: I am saying that if your backend is with Firebase, it cannot move elsewhere, it must run on the Google servers.

Answer (score 0):

What do you actually want to transfer to superhosting.bg - you want to use a superhosting-owned domain to attach your app to or you want to use their hosting?

As Frank van Puffelen answered above, for the latter just follow bith platforms' instructions on set up. However, if you're already using firebase, I'd stick with that.

For using custom domain on superhosting with firebase, you need to add the TXT records shown in firebase to your DNS provider (superhosting). Essentially, you will need to edit the DNS Zone of your domain.

- In superhosting this is done through their cPanel. Then you go to DNS zone editor and find the domain you want to edit. Once here, you have to option to add TXT registry.
- To get this TXT registry, go to Add Custom Domain in firebase (docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain). They'll give you a TXT code you copy in the aforementioned location in cPanel.

Et voila!